# Changing XIB on rotating doesn't work correctly on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I have trouble with my app running on iOS 8. When i start app in portrait mode, its work correctly, but when start it in landscape mode i have things like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ds-eOfxhPGc&list=UUWJmewTedt8KvB5kjTam8FA

I use 2 XIB and change it on rotating by this code. Its work great on iOS 7, but doesn't work correctly on iOS 8

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation  duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) )
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-landscape", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-landscape", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];

    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is deprecated in iOS 8. Use `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` instead. If you need to get the orientation, use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`.